# How to add to HTML table from html/php form?

Tags: php, html

I want to create a form with 2 fields and 2 buttons.
field 1: *NAME* & filed 2: *ADDRESS*
button 1: *SUBMIT* & button 2: *ERASE*

I want to ADD from the form into **field 1**
i want to ADD from the    form into **field 2**

```
    <td>field 1</td>
<td class='latency' id='field 1' endpoint='field 2'>&nbsp;</td>
```

**The code is written is js and the htl code looks like this**

```
     <td>US-East)</td>
    <td class='latency' id='us-east-1' endpoint='https://amazon.com/'>&nbsp;</td>
```

How can I written a php/html form to do this? Or where can I get info on how to do this?

Comment: I strongly suggest you search the web for tutorials on creating forms using php and how to erase a form and try to come up with some code, then if you hit a wall, come back and ask for some assistance. Also make sure to post all relevant code in your questions.

Comment: @dalelandry what do i google.i tried to do php/forms and there was a lot of info. can you be more specific?  this way i can just find the answers i need. thanks

Comment: Well start using a search that suits what you are trying to accomplish. Be literal in what you ask search engine for. You want a form that collects name and address. I would suggest looking into html5 forms. Get the form constructed properly and then search how to add an empty form button to your form. What is this form for? Is it for DB collection or login credentials? What is its purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE ON SECURITY:** When using data input from an end user one should always clean the users entries. There are built in php functions for that purpose. I am not getting into this in detail in my answer, I am simply showing you how to achieve the functionality you are asking to achieve in regards to FORM creation and display of dynamic values from said form.

HTML SPECIAL CHARACTERS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Your starting point will be html, create a form with method POST.
`<form action="formpage.php" method="post"></form>` <-- `formpage.php` should be the php page you wish to send the data to for processing.

The ***action*** attribute will reference the page you wish to have your form post the results of the inputs to ---> `$_POST['input-name']`

The ***method*** attribute specifies how to send form-data 
(the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).
The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get") or as HTTP post transaction (with method="post").

A typical form would look like the following.

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter a Name" required>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="" required>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"><!--// Will reset the form to their original form values-->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">    
</form>
```

Now, once the user hits the submit button, three values are sent via the HTTP post request. These are referenced in the input fields as the `name` attributes.

1. name
2. address
3. submit

On mypage.php we can now reference those values sent from the user input using those posted globals.

```
$_POST['name'] =    // the input field that has the name attribute set to `"name"`

$_POST['address'] = // the input field that has the name attribute set to `"address"`

$_POST['submit'] =  // the input field that has the name attribute set to `"submit"`
```

***EDIT:*** Dynamic creation to create a table and display results of form

```
$table = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // check to see if the submit button was hit and isset
    // assign the post values to variables
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); 
    $address = htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']);

    // if you want to create the table dynamically now.
    $table .= '
              <table>
                  <tr>';
    if($name!==NULL){
        $table .= '
        <td>Name: '.$name.'</td>';
    }
    if($address!==NULL){
        $table .= '
        <td>address: '.$address.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '
                  </tr>
              <table>';
}
```

To place table in your code, simple echo out the `$table` variable in your `HTML` where you want the table to go.

```
<?=$table?>
```

***END EDIT***

The php code that defines the variables used would need to be declared at the top of the page above the `<html>` tag.

We can also reference these variables in our HTML code on that same page as well. 
`<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`

```
<td class='latency' id='<?=$name?>' endpoint='<?=$address?>'>&nbsp;</td>
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: once i do the form and link it to the .php file should echo the results in the table like: 'echo  <td>$name</td>
        <td class='latency' id='$name' endpoint='$address'>&nbsp;</td>' ?

Comment: If your form is posting to the same page and echoing out those result on the same page then yes, just call on the variables you have set for those post values and placing them in your desired section of your table. If you are sending these values to another php page, then you will need to store them globally in a session perhaps or using a post url method and then getting them using the $_GET global method on the other php page. Hope that helps out.

Comment: How do i write it so it creates a new table row with the variables? can i write is as <? echo <td>$name</td> <td class='latency' id='$name' endpoint='$address'>&nbsp;</td> ?> OR do i need another php file/script for that? @dalelandry

Comment: You can call on those variables `anywhere` in your code if the values are in the global scope $_POST. So you can redefine them on the page like `$name = $_POST['name'];` then `echo $name;` or you can use the POST value directly on the page echoing  `$_POST['name']`. And yes the HTML <td> line I added in the answer is an example of how to echo out a post value.

Comment: will this create new rows as new data from the form is added?

Comment: No, you would need to do that dynamically using a foreach loop. foreach will parse the data and return a value for each instance of an arrays value it finds. please update your code to add code that correlates with an instance where more than one value of an input may be present.

Comment: I added a bit that should help to explain how this could be done dynamically. Please look the code over in detail, everything you need to recreate this is there. Best.

Comment: This code is subject to XSS attacks and shouldn't be used as-is.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` (or equivalent) when injecting arbitrary data into the context of HTML.

Comment: No problem, I removed my downvote.  Also, just to clarify, even if the data doesn't come from a form you should still use `htmlspecialchars()`.  Inevitably, some dynamic data from somewhere will get used in your application, and even if there's no immediate security issue, it's pretty easy to break your HTML.  (Plus, this is how security issues end up forming later... data is assumed safe because the source may have been before, but isn't now.)

Comment: ok what about the table id? <table id="pinger"> do i put that inside the form id? because i tried to use the form codes with the js codes i have for the pinger and it did nothing. @dalelandry

Comment: this is what i have thus far::: <form action="mypage.php" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<span><?=$name?></span>
<td class='latency' id='<?=$name?>' endpoint='<?=$address?>'>&nbsp;</td>

Comment: ok im having issues trying to make the code look presentable..

Comment: <form action="mypage.php" method="post" action table id="pinger"="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter a Name" required>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
<span><?=$name?></span> <td class='latency' id='<?=$name?>' endpoint='<?=$address?>' input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">&nbsp;</td>

Comment: <script>
function deleteRow(r) {   var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i); 
}
</script>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // check to see if the submit button was hit and isset
    // assign the post values to variables
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); 
    $address = htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']);
 // if you want to create the table dynamically now.
    $table .= '
              <table>
                  <tr>';
    if($name!==NULL){
        $table .= '
        <td>Name: '.$name.'</td>';
    }
    if($address!==NULL){
        $table .= '
        <td>address: '.$address.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '
                  </tr>

Comment: // define variables
$name = $address = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $address = test_input($_POST["email"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

Comment: thisn is driving me nuts. i cant find anything online to help me. every time i google php html forms, edit, delete i get mysql info. what can i google to help me with this. i cant get anything to work

Comment: `<input type="reset" value="Reset">` try adding this to your form just above the submit button inside the form

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset